# Using an 3 phase rcd with a single phase supply

Tags: electrical, security

Europe electrical system user here. TT-grounding system, if that information is needed.

At the moment I have a single phase supply, but the panel is ready for three phase power. I plan to switch to three phase power in the future.

Therefor I have 4 wires (3xphase and 1 neutral) to the single phase meter. Of them, only phase 1 and neutral is connected at the meter. The others are unused and disconnected also in the panel. In the panel all three phases got shorted together, to power all the circuits until I switch to three phase supply.

My question is about the outgoing 3 phase RCD to the range: I was told that the RCD won't have an effect, since it is feed with a single phase, distributed over its 3 phase terminals. Is that true? Do I need to change the wiring of the three phase range? At the moment the RCD seems to be working, as the "test" button trips the RCD. The range can be connected both single phase as three-phase.

Further precautions:

The phase 2+3 of the supply are physically disconnected, so that an eventual change at the supply meter won't produce catastrophic results. Obviously also to keep the 2 unused phase wires tension-free. The panel has warnings for the phase shorting, for anybody working on it.

I am not concerned about neutral overload, as every single phase circuit has the right breakers (mostly RCBOs, but also some RCDs with each 2 MCB), and the single three-phase circuit (to the range) is protected by a breaker that also protects the neutral (4 pole MCB, not 3+n MCB). That should be fine?

I do not intend to have "real" three phase power while having only single phase supply. I just want to have the option to switch to three phase power in the future and have an secure installation meanwhile.

In the picture, the basic scheme of the installation. Ground not shown.
[image]

Comment: The traditional solution for driving three -phase from two--phase or one-phase is a motor/generator set. These days there is probably an electronic AC-to-DC-to-AC solution driving a three-phase inverter. Don't forget to account for power loss in that, and for the fact that to get the same power from a lower voltage source you need to draw more amperage.

Comment: @keshlam sorry for sounding rude in my previous comment. I guess I need to clarify that I do not intend to have "real" 3 phase power with a single phase supply. The range tolerates both 3phase as single phase. I just want to have the entire system secure and ready for an future 3 phase supply.

Comment: @keshlam - and, yes, one can use a "phase converter" to extract 3-phase from a single phase.